# What does it mean exactly if two types are "compatible" to each other in C?

Tags: c, types, language-lawyer, compatibility, terminology

In the C standard is stated (emphasize mine):

> Two types have compatible type **if their types are the same**. Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for declarators. 56)
>
> 56)Two types **need not be identical to be compatible**.
>
> Source: C18, §6.2.7/1 - "Compatible type and composite type"

The information I get from these sentences is not much and not very helpful. The cited sections in general also provide no further information about what "*compatible*" exactly is/means.

I know now, that two types are compatible if they have the same type, but also can be compatible if they don't have the same type/be identical.

One place I found out where two non-identical types are compatible to each other is if I compare one type to a `typedef`d type of this original type or to any `typedef`d type of the original type, both types are compatible, as explained in the examples to §6.7.8/4 and /5:

§6.7.8/4:

> **EXAMPLE 1** After
>
> ```
> typedef int MILES, KLICKSP(); 
> typedef struct {doublehi, lo; } range;
> ```
>
> the constructions
>
> ```
> MILES distance; 
> extern KLICKSP *metricp;
> range x;
> range z,*zp;
> ```
>
> are all valid declarations. The type of `distance` is `int`, that of `metricp` is "pointer to function with no parameter specification returning `int`", and that of `x` and `z` is the specified structure; `zp` is a pointer to such a structure. **The object `distance` has a type compatible with any other `int` object**.

and

§6.7.8/5:

> **EXAMPLE 2** After the declarations
>
> ```
> typedef structs1 { int x; } t1, *tp1;
> typedef structs2 { int x; } t2, *tp2;
> ```
>
> **type `t1`and the type pointed to by `tp1` are compatible. Type `t1` is also compatible with type `structs1`, but not compatible with the types `structs2`, `t2`, the type pointed to by `tp2`, or `int`**.

but it only shows one example regarding the `typedef`, where types can be *compatible* if not identical.

My questions:

- Under which (all) circumstances can two types be *compatible* if they are not identical exactly? , and
- What is a "*compatible type*" exactly? / What does it mean if two types are *compatible* to each other?
- What specifies "*compatibility*"?

That is what I am looking for and couldn't found in the standard until yet.

If possible, please refer to sections from standard in the answers.

---

#### Additional research:

I discovered that compatibility is not mandatory related to range, representation or behavior:

§6.2.5/15:

> The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*. **The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`**.45)
>
> 45)`CHAR_MIN`, defined in `<limits.h>`, will have one of the values `0` or `SCHAR_MIN`, and this can be used to distinguish the two options. **Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either**.

---

#### Cited sections from the first quote:

The cited sections 6.7.2, 6.7.3 and 6.7.6 do not explain more what a *compatible type* is, they only mandate rules for specific cases when a type shall be a *compatible type*.

§6.7.2/4:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type.  The choice of type is implementation-defined, 131) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. The enumerated type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.

§6.7.3/11:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type.

§6.7.6.1/2:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

§6.7.6.2/6:

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value.  If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

§6.7.6.3/15:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.149) Moreover,the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types. If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions. If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list,both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)
>
> 149)If both function types are "old style", parameter types are not compared.

---

#### Related:

- [Compatible types and structures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904668)
- [Is a redeclaration of an untagged structure a compatible type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445629)
- [Compatible types and argument type qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215686)
- [compatible types vs. strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010971)
- [Are these compatible function types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743887)
- [Compatible types and ignoring top-level qualifiers in the C type system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49479461/12139179)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually comes from this:

> 2. All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So from that you can see that anything that is allowed by the standard to work here, will be by necessity, compatible. For example the type `int []` is distinct from `int [10]` but they are compatible, because the standard allows you to declare

```
extern int foo[];
```

in one file and define

```
int foo[10];
```

in another file, and access `foo` using the external identifier as an array of unknown size - therefore the these types are compatible, but not identical.

It is stated explicitly in [C11/18 6.7.6.2p6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p6):

> 6. For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

Comment: Thank you for the array compatibility example. But in the case of the `typedef`s for example the types do not refer to the same object or function; which in turn should mean that a "compatible type" is not only related or originated to/from declarations that refer to the same object or function. A "*compatible type*" must further depict something quite different although this is one of the cases where types are compatible. It can not come from that only.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the compatibility is only of importance when you must refer to the **same object or function** using distinct types.

Comment: So, the goal of "compatibility" is that I *can* refer to f.e. `distance` in the example using a pointer to `int` instead of only a pointer to `MILES`, right?

Comment: The primary goal of "compatibility" is to specify what is a legal re-declaration. If an object or function has two declarations with incompatible types and both declarations are visible in the same compilation unit, the compiler is required to report an error. If the incompatible declarations are in different compilation units, the behavior is undefined.
Types do not have to be identical in order to be compatible, because array bounds or parameter lists (prototypes) may be missing from one of the declarations. In C++ the prototype-related cases are impossible so only array bounds remain.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your question! I bumped into it while trying to reveal what may stand behind the phrase "Two types have compatible type if their types are the same". You helped me to realize that it only states a *sufficient* condition for two types to be compatible.

In my understanding, the most important property of the compatibility relation is that it overcomes the *scope* of a struct/union tag or a typedef name. In particular, C17 directly states that (§6.7.2.3/5):

> Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in
> different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types.

That is, the same struct/union declaration used in two or more files results in different, yet compatible types.