# Two types have compatible type if their types are the same: confused

Tags: c, types, language-lawyer, c23

C2x (N2596), 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type, 1:

> Two types have *compatible type* if their types are the same.

The grammar of that sentence is confusing.

For example:

- How type can have a type? Or what does "their types" mean?
- What does it mean "compatible type"? Any examples?

Please clarify who knows the topic well.

UPD. Here is the rephrased sentence:

> Two types are compatible if they are the same.

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622025/what-does-it-mean-exactly-if-two-types-are-compatible-to-each-other-in-c

Comment: You're right that the grammar of that sentence is horrible.  It should be "A type is *compatible* with itself."  To answer your question of what "compatible type" means, you should look at all the other rules in the definition, because being the same type is *sufficient* but not *necessary*.

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, it does, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence means if the type `X` and the type `Y` are the same type, then `X` is compatible with `Y` (and vice-versa, of course).

In mathematical terms, it means compatibility is reflexive (any type is compatible with itself).

Comment: Why not "`X` is equal to `Y`"?